# Trying to use MSVC to attach to Inno-Setup process to debug a DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, inno-setup

I'm happy with the Pascal script I have in Inno Setup. My setup script calls some entry points in a DLL I wrote in C++ using MSVC 2010. I'm trying to use the MSVC debugger to step thru my C++ code in the DLL.
So, I launch MSVC in Administrator mode, and in Inno Setup I run my installer until Inno Setup hits a breakpoint in my Pascal code. Then, in MSVC, from the Debug menu I use "Attach Process..." to attach the MSVC debugger to the relevant process in Inno Setup, and set breakpoints. I find four relevant processes, two requiring Administrator privilege and two others. I attach all four.
This is where things go wonky. Even with the processes attached, my breakpoints in the C++ DLL code all turn into empty circles, and sure enough, they are never hit even when I use Inno Setup's debugger to step over or into a call to my DLL. So, what am I doing wrong here? I just want the MSVC debugger to hit a breakpoint in my DLL.
Two of the four relevant processes have ".exe" extension and two have ".tmp". I probably only need one but I'm not sure which.

Comment: Are you sure that you aren't trying to debug Release DLLs that don't have any symbol? Or maybe try to explicitely call [DebugBreak](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-debugbreak) within your DLL?

Comment: Make sure that the symbols are loaded for your module. The info is displayed in the modules window of the debugger. Right clicking on the module should also provide an option to load the symbols. Moreover, ensure that you are attaching the debugger in native mode rather than to debug .NET code. There should be an option in the attach window for this

Comment: The problem seems to relate to non-local files. Today I did a clean/rebuild and got C1083 on source files that absolutely have the right path to a network volume. The files exist.